# java can't find local variable in reterofit 2 api call

Tags: java, android, api

I have done an API call to retrieve a list of messages, then i want to check if each message has a flag of 2 and then if it does do another API call to receive information on whether the message has been "paid" and if it has alter the object message to paid = true;

Here is my failed attempt.

```
for (int i = 0; i < chatHistory.getData().size(); i++) {
    final ChatMessage chatMessage = chatHistory.getData().get(i).getBody();
    if (chatMessage.flag.equals("2")) {
         RestClient.getInstance().getApiService().getPaymentRequest(chatMessage.payment_request_id, new Callback<SinglePaymentRequest>() {

         @Override
         public void success(SinglePaymentRequest singlePaymentRequest, Response response) {
               Payment payment = singlePaymentRequest.getPayment();
               if(payment.getStatus().equals("paid")) {
                     chatMessage.isPaid=true;
               }
          }

          @Override
          public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
              System.out.println("fail");
          }
      });
  }

  chatMessages.add(chatMessage);
  Log.e("chat history", chatMessage.from);
}

addData(chatMessages);
```

The problem I am facing is that the api call cannot find local variable chatmessage, any ideas as to why this is?

Thanks

Comment: `addData(chatMessages);`,  `chatMessages` has already fallen out of the scope, since you are not in the loop anymore

Comment: Kevin Esche is correct declare var chatMessage before for loop

Comment: chatMessages is declared out of the loop,

Comment: @AdamKatz i think it should would unless `final ChatMessage chatMessage = chatHistory.getData().get(i).getBody();` is not null. Can you let me know the exception you get?

Comment: with breakpoints, I get into the if statement where flag equals 2, but when the api is called suddenly chatmessage is null

Comment: @AdamKatz I think the scope of the chatMessage is lost before you get the response. try to add the chatMessage to a collection like map based on the payment_request_id and retrieve the chatmessage from the collection when you get the response from the Api

Comment: Thanks this is definitely the right track, I am quite inexperienced with Java so struggling through it a little slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the bit of code `new Callback<SinglePaymentRequest>()` that creates your new Callback object?  It does not have access to the variables outside it, for good reason too.

What you should be doing, is calling a setter method that's part of your container class (the one that is the parent of the Callback) that will, in turn manipulate the values that you want to change.